# TinyMCE inserts a <script> tag pointing to themes/advanced/langs/en.js inside my text

Tags: tinymce

There is a previous question to this issue but it has no posted solution. This is for a backend I didn't programmed but I'm mantaining right now and there's this issue. TinyMCE is initialized this way:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "style,paste",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "pasteword",
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    paste_remove_spans: true
});
```

And now we found an error for one of our sites with a JS error in IE: 'tinyMCE is undefined' on line 1 of file "themes/advanced/langs/en.js". This is the code we found in one of the texts edited with TinyMCE:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">
<script src="../../../../js/kicms/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
Como resultado de las actividades del sector en el mes de Julio de 2010, se registr&oacute; una variaci&oacute;n en los precios relevados en el canal SPM de

(...)
```

(The rest of the text is normal/OK.)

Why is that  tag in there? Any clue about this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a problem for IE when using certain types of compressed JavaScripts.

I suspect that js/kicms/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js is a compressed file (open in a text editor to see if it is jumbled). Try using an uncompressed version (human readable).

Your call to TinyMCE should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,filemanager",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/example.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Plus, you may want to try downloading the latest version of TinyMCE code and try it with the uncompressed files:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php

EDIT:

Sorry, I misunderstood. Just remove the script tag and your error should go away. I suspect a developer was in a hurry and forgot to remove the tag.

Comment: The bad thing is that my IE error is in a page that only displays text, it's a front-end page that displays the text edited in the back-end, there's no TinyMCE in that page, but the script tag is "saved" into the text when editing it in the backend.

Comment: Just remove the script tag, it must of been left in by mistake. Then it should work without the error.

Comment: I did removed the tag from the database text field, but it seems to be added to the text when the users creates a new record.

Comment: You will need to find the code that generates the text and remove it from there.